# Javascript update multiple json files access is a single function

Tags: javascript, json, function

I am looking to get the data from 2 json files every 60 seconds.  One file contains news articles, and the second file contains comments relating to each article.

I can download the comments for updates every 60 seconds, and pass the json to the results function.

```
function updateData() {

 var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");

 xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        //showResults(xobj.responseText);
        showResults(JSON.parse(xobj.response));
      }
 };

 xobj.open("GET", "comments.json", true);
 xobj.send();

 setTimeout(updateData, 60000);
}
```

However, how do I open 2 json files, and pass the results to the showResults function using the callback?

I am trying to display the topics and comments together.  So for each topic, get the comments for that topic.  I can get this working by using globals, but I think that is a poor approach.

```
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
    topics = JSON.parse(xobj.response);
    }
  };

  xobj2.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj2.readyState == 4 && xobj2.status == "200") {
    comments = JSON.parse(xobj2.response);
  }
 };
```

I saw a solution that downloaded multiple json files, but then we do not know what file would download first, so I would be unable to use:

```
showResults(JSON.parse(xobj.response), JSON.parse(xobj2.response));
```

Because it is asynchronous, and the order could differ, and showResults would need to expect the order to be (topics, comments).

I am looking for a way that the current function can have access to the data from both of the files.

```
 function showResults(json) {
 // Have both here to display
 }
```

Is using globals acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Promise.all` to combine the two promises that you get from reading the two files.  This will give you a new promise that resolves when both of the other promises are ready, and it will resolve with an array of both promises' results.

For instance:

```
const combinedPromise = Promise.all([readFile1(), readFile2()]);
combinedPromise.then(([file1, file2]) => // ... code that uses both files
```

Comment: Can I be assured the order of the results?  Thanks for the comment.  I added fetch to get the data to take advantage for promises.    Promise.all([ fetch("../downloads/news.json"), fetch("../downloads/comments.json")])  .  I then call .then(function (data) { showResults(data) });   In showResults I use data[0] to get news data, and data[1] to get comments data.  This is working, but my fear is the order.  Will data[0] always be news, and data[1] always be the second file?

Comment: Yes, the order is fixed: whatever order you give the arguments to `Promise.all` is the same order as the results in the first `.then` chained to the resulting promise.  But don't take my word for it ;)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all has a full explanation of `Promise.all`, and it confirms what I'm saying about the order.

Comment: Also don't forget that you can use destructuring here, so instead of making a `showResults` function like `data => { use(data[0]); use(data[1]); }` you can simply destructure the two parts of data in the arguments, ie. `([newsData, commentData]) => { use(newsData); use(commentData); }`

Comment: Oh and also, if I answered your question, please do check the checkmark for it to indicate as much :)